# Group by pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data

```
mm_id                           11.02.2016  12.02.2016  13.02.2016  14.02.2016  15.02.2016  16.02.2016  17.02.2016
b2b5b93270cb217310b0719946b0afee    0            0          0           242         0           0           0
71f464119a2d43834c3be0af362487bc    0            23         0           0           0           0           0   
afad5e5f9c3ba9df885eba1557ab7c73    1            0          0           22          0           0           0
```

And I need to group it with data. But I don't know how I can transfer to another format.
Desire output (I need to get list of unique `ID` to every `data`):

```
day
2016-03-01    [00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401, 00102b98bd9,  ...]
2016-03-02    [00102b98bd9e71da3cf23fd1f599408d, 0012ea90a6d,  ...]
2016-03-03    [00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401, 00102b98bd9,  ...]
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the dates in your desired output should be the columns in your input? It's not the case at the moment...

Comment: I want to change that and get smth like `ID,"day"
00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401,2016-03-01
00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401,2016-03-03
00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401,2016-03-04
00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401,2016-03-05
`

Comment: And if value in date == 0, don't use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First step**: transform the dataframe

```
df = df.set_index('mm_id', drop=True).transpose()
```

Output:

```
mm_id       b2b5b93270cb217310b0719946b0afee  \
11.02.2016                                 0   
12.02.2016                                 0   
13.02.2016                                 0   
14.02.2016                               242   
15.02.2016                                 0   
16.02.2016                                 0   
17.02.2016                                 0   

mm_id       71f464119a2d43834c3be0af362487bc  afad5e5f9c3ba9df885eba1557ab7c73  
11.02.2016                                 0                                 1  
12.02.2016                                23                                 0  
13.02.2016                                 0                                 0  
14.02.2016                                 0                                22  
15.02.2016                                 0                                 0  
16.02.2016                                 0                                 0  
17.02.2016                                 0                                 0
```

**Second step**: apply a function

```
In [10]: df.apply(lambda row: row[row != 0].index.tolist(), axis=1)
Out[10]: 
11.02.2016                 ['afad5e5f9c3ba9df885eba1557ab7c73']
12.02.2016                 ['71f464119a2d43834c3be0af362487bc']
13.02.2016                                                   []
14.02.2016    ['b2b5b93270cb217310b0719946b0afee', 'afad5e5f...
15.02.2016                                                   []
16.02.2016                                                   []
17.02.2016                                                   []
```

This gets the id of users with non-zero value.

Comment: Function returns `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (9296) into shape (18089)`

Comment: Could you try this first, just to see? `df.apply(lambda row: str(row[row != 0].index.tolist()), axis=1)`

Comment: Can you say, how I can write it to `excel`? Usually I use `to_excel`, but it write lists with points `[ddc6cc21999d77351381e7e44892ffb9, 825b3c223af..., b2b5b93270cb217310b0719946b0afee]`

Comment: I think your `drop=True` for setting index isn't neccessary, it's need for `reset_index`.

Comment: @AntonProtopopov you're right, but it's strange that it says so in the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)...

Comment: @hellmoore: Sorry I don't have any experience with `to_excel`.

Comment: @hellmoore, @IanS you could also use oneliner: `(df.iloc[:, 1:].T * df.mm_id).apply(lambda x: x[x !=''].tolist(), axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you could do following with `applymap`, `numpy broadcasting`, `pd.melt`, and `groupby`:

```
In [94]: df
Out[94]:
                              mm_id  11.02.2016  12.02.2016  13.02.2016  14.02.2016  15.02.2016  16.02.2016  17.02.2016  
0  b2b5b93270cb217310b0719946b0afee           0           0           0         242           0           0           0
1  71f464119a2d43834c3be0af362487bc           0          23           0           0           0           0           0
2  afad5e5f9c3ba9df885eba1557ab7c73           1           0           0          22           0           0           0

# values from dates
df_values = df.iloc[:, 1:]

# first change numbers to dummies for dates, i.e. 1 for non zero elements
df2 = df_values.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x >= 1 else 0)        

# fill data with mm_id
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df2.values * df.mm_id[:, None], columns=df2.columns)

# melt all together
df4 = pd.melt(df3, var_name='date', value_name='id') 

# fill empty strings with NaN to drop in the final groupby
df4 = df4.replace('', np.nan)    

# final groupby by date, select id column, and then apply pd.Sereis with dropna and get unique values
df5 = df4.groupby('date')['id'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).dropna().unique())
```

Results from each step:

```
In [133]: df_values
Out[133]:
   11.02.2016  12.02.2016  13.02.2016  14.02.2016  15.02.2016  16.02.2016  17.02.2016
0           0           0           0         242           0           0           0
1           0          23           0           0           0           0           0
2           1           0           0          22           0           0           0

In [146]: df2
Out[146]:
   11.02.2016  12.02.2016  13.02.2016  14.02.2016  15.02.2016  16.02.2016  17.02.2016
0           0           0           0           1           0           0           0
1           0           1           0           0           0           0           0
2           1           0           0           1           0           0           0

In [147]: df3
Out[147]:
                         11.02.2016                        12.02.2016 13.02.2016                        14.02.2016 15.02.2016 16.02.2016 17.02.2016
0                                                                                 b2b5b93270cb217310b0719946b0afee
1                                    71f464119a2d43834c3be0af362487bc
2  afad5e5f9c3ba9df885eba1557ab7c73                                               afad5e5f9c3ba9df885eba1557ab7c73

In [148]: df4
Out[148]:
          date                                id
0   11.02.2016                               NaN
1   11.02.2016                               NaN
2   11.02.2016  afad5e5f9c3ba9df885eba1557ab7c73
3   12.02.2016                               NaN
4   12.02.2016  71f464119a2d43834c3be0af362487bc
5   12.02.2016                               NaN
6   13.02.2016                               NaN
7   13.02.2016                               NaN
8   13.02.2016                               NaN
9   14.02.2016  b2b5b93270cb217310b0719946b0afee
10  14.02.2016                               NaN
11  14.02.2016  afad5e5f9c3ba9df885eba1557ab7c73
12  15.02.2016                               NaN
13  15.02.2016                               NaN
14  15.02.2016                               NaN
15  16.02.2016                               NaN
16  16.02.2016                               NaN
17  16.02.2016                               NaN
18  17.02.2016                               NaN
19  17.02.2016                               NaN
20  17.02.2016                               NaN

In [149]: df5
Out[149]:
date
11.02.2016                   [afad5e5f9c3ba9df885eba1557ab7c73]
12.02.2016                   [71f464119a2d43834c3be0af362487bc]
13.02.2016                                                   []
14.02.2016    [b2b5b93270cb217310b0719946b0afee, afad5e5f9c3...
15.02.2016                                                   []
16.02.2016                                                   []
17.02.2016                                                   []
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! See answer above, there is a decided shortly

Comment: @hellmoore yeah, definitely it's much simplier and faster.